# Why is the adj. word "frozen" after the verb in "Mr. Dursley sat frozen in his armchair."?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, literature

Why is the adjective word "frozen" after the verb in *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*?

> Mr. Dursley sat frozen in his armchair.

If I change the sentence to

> Mr. Dursley sat happy in his armchair.

The sentence is wrong, because "happy and "frozen" are adjective words. Why can't I replace "frozen" with "happy"?

In my opinion, the "frozen" is an adjective word. It can't go after the verb "sat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjectives can be used this way, though it is less common.

Some verbs can be used as linking verbs. The most common linking verb is "am/is/are" but as you see in your example "sit" or "stand" can also be linking verbs.

So just as

> Mr Durstley was frozen in his armchair.  (is correct)
>
> Mr Durstley sat frozen in his armchair.  (also correct)
>
> Mr Durstley sat happy in his armchair.   (correct but rare)

The last is rare, because usually we would be able to use an adverb

> Mr Durstley sat happily in his armchair. (describing the sitting, rather than the man)

"Frozenly" would not be correct, as we are not describing the action of sitting, but man.

Comment: It isn't an adjective here. It describes how the man was sitting.

Answer (score 0):

**Verbs that describe body positions:**

"Mr. Dursley sat frozen in his armchair." in a book called Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone.

to **sit, stand, kneel, crawl, for example**. **These are all intransitive verbs**.

They do not take objects but are often used with adverbs:

- The baby sat happily in his high chair.
- The man stood shakily on his injured legs.
- The boy crawled quickly across the floor.
- The priest knelt carefully at the altar.

frozen is usually an adjective:
The **frozen ground** was very hard.

However, in "sit frozen", that describes **how** the person sat, just as in **sit contentedly, sit stiffly, sit elegantly**. It functions as an adverb. It describes the manner in which he sat.

> Essential Meaning of adverb : a word that describes a verb, an
> adjective, another adverb, or a sentence and that is often used to
> show time, **manner**, place, or degree In "arrived early," "runs
> slowly," "stayed home," and "works hard" the words "early," "slowly,"
> "home," and "hard" are adverbs.

[Merriam Webster - Adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adverb?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)